# Determining the type from a smart pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that currently takes in two template parameters. One is expected to be the smart pointer, and the other is expected to be the object type. For example, `SmartPtr<MyObject>` as the first template parameter and `MyObject` as the second template parameter.

```
template <typename T, typename TObject>
```

I would like to know whether I can determine the second parameter, `MyObject`, automatically from the first parameter `SmartPtr<MyObject>` or not so that my template function is written like this:

```
template <typename T>
```

And the type `TObject` in the original template function is automatically determined from `T` which is expected to be a smart pointer.

As requested, here is the function declaration and its use:

```
template <typename T, typename TObject>
T* CreateOrModifyDoc(T* doc, MyHashTable& table)
{
    T* ptr = NULL;

    if (!table.FindElement(doc->id, ptr))
    {
        table.AddElement(doc->id, new TObject());
        table.FindElement(doc->id, ptr);
    }       

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the function into your question?

Comment: We can guess, but in order to fully answer your question you'll need to show us the function declaration and how you're calling it as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know that the first template parameter will be the smart pointer type, why not declare your function with only one parameter and use it as such:

```
template<typename T>
void WhatIsIt(SmartPtr<T> ptr)
{ 
    printf("It is a: %s" typeid(T).name());
}
```

Comment: Seriously? downvote because I chose string as an example code? I just made that up, the function body doesn't even need to be there...

Comment: @Dan F: No, because you chose string as a type identifier. What's wrong with a typedef?

Comment: Whats wrong with having a string version of the type contained within the smart pointer?

Comment: @nightcracker:  How is that relevant to the validity of this answer?

Comment: Because you should store the type itself. If the user wants a string he/she can use `typeid`.

Comment: @nightcracker : The first two lines are all that's needed to demonstrate the suggestion; the function body is irrelevant.

Comment: @nightcracker: The type itself is "stored", as `T`

Comment: @nightcracker, here let me fix that for you.

Comment: I'll remove the downvote (if I could), but I still find storing the type as a string itself not necessary and against common convention.

Comment: @nightcracker : Nothing in his code "stores" anything as a string; it's merely intended to show the syntax for getting at a template's argument types when the template type itself is known. For the OP's code, it would translate to something like `template<typename TObject> SmartPtr<TObject> CreateOrModifyDoc(SmartPtr<TObject> doc, MyHashTable& table) {`.

Comment: @nightcracker: beware of how critic you are with other answers, you may get paid with the same code. This answer is right, either with the string or without, whether a stored string or a `type_info` object is a better solution to obtain the name of the type is a completely different discussion, and one for which you will find strong arguments in both directions.

Comment: Apart from the heated discussion =P, I selected this as an answer (and upvoted it) because it answered the question directly. There are a couple of answers below that work in my particular situation but becuase I didn't phrase the question properly I didn't select any of them as the answer (although I wish there was a `second answer` `third answer` or `also check this answer` buttons for any future stakoverflow'er who comes across questions where multiple answers may be valid).

Comment: @nightcracker: You can remove downvotes by clicking on the downvote arrow again.

Comment: @mkb: I'm not stupid. You can't remove it anymore after the answer hasn't changed for 30 minutes or so. But I already removed it now.

Answer (score 3):

If the classes that can serve as the first template parameter can be made to provide a handy typedef by a common name, you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr
{
  public:
    typedef T element_type;

  // ...
};


template <typename PtrType, typename ObjType=PtrType::element_type>
void your_function_here(const PtrType& ptr)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @ildjarn:  Good call.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Did you write SmartPtr?  If so, add this to it

```
  typedef T element_type;
```

Comment: Use `element_type`, not `TDeref`, so that the nested type's name is consistent with `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 1):

All smart pointers I know of support the member `::element_type`. For example boost's shared_ptr: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#element_type, but also the `std` smart pointers support this convention.

```
template <typename T> class SharedPtr {
public:
    typedef T element_type;

    // ...
};
```